# Probability that the item tested is defective given that the testing QC procedure indicates it to be defective

Tags: probability, self-study

A given lot of items has $2$% defectives. Given the following information about the quality testing procedure:

P [Testing QC procedure indicates an item tested as good | item is indeed good] = $0.95$

P [Testing QC procedure indicates an item tested as defective | item is indeed defective] = $0.94$

I am required to compute the probability that the item tested is defective given that the testing QC procedure indicates it to be defective.

**Here is what I did**

$\text{P(Item tested is Defective} | \text{Testing Procedure indicates it to be defective}) = \frac{\text{P(Item is actually defective, testing procedure indicates it to be defective)}}{\text{P(Testing procedure indicates it to be defective)}}$

It can further be written as:

$\frac{\text{P(Item is actually defective)P(testing procedure indicates it to be defective)}}{\text{P(Testing procedure indicates it to be defective)}}$

The denominator can be written as:

$\text{P(Testing procedure indicates it to be defective)} = $

$\text{P(Testing procedure indicates it to be defective | It is actually defective) +}$

$\text{P(Testing procedure indicates it to be defective | It is actually good)} $ = $0.94 + 0.05 = 0.99$

I have used here the two information provided.

For the numerator, I can use the information provided in the following way:

$\text{P(Item is actually defective, testing procedure indicates it to be defective)} = \text{P [Testing QC procedure indicates an item tested as defective | item is indeed defective]} * 
\text{P(Item is indeed defective)} = 0.94*0.02$.

Now, using the values of numerator and denomitaor, I will get:

$\frac{0.94*0.02}{0.99} = 0.018$.

I hope I have followed the right procedure. I am getting this answer but the textbook answer is showing me $0.28$ as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\text{Item defective and Test says defective})\neq P(\text{Item defective})P(\text{Test says defective})$
because these events are dependent. Let's rename the events as $D$: item defective, $TD$: test says defective. We want to find $P(D|TD)$, which is
$$P(D|TD)=\frac{P(D\cap TD)}{P(TD)}=\frac{P(TD|D)P(D)}{P(TD)}$$

$P(D)$ and $P(TD|D)$ are already given as $0.02$ and $0.94$ respectively. The denominator can be calculated as
$$P(TD)=P(TD|D)P(D)+P(TD|D')P(D')$$
The second summand has probabilities $P(TD|D')=0.05$ and $P(D')=0.98$. When substituted, you'll find the given answer.

Comment: Thanks @gunes. I got the correct answer.